# Stop code execution after redirect

Tags: go

```
//main.go
func (self *GoodsController) GoodsEditGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    tmpID, ok := vars["id"]
    sess := session.Instance(w, r)

    if !ok {
        tpl.Error("Invalid goods id")
    }

    id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(tmpID, 10, 64)

    goods, err := service.NewGoodsService(w, r).GetGoodsDetail(id)

    if err != nil {
        //This utility function will not stop the rest of the code being executed
        util.RedirectWithMessage(w, r, err.Error(), "/system/inventory/goods")
    }

    //This line will be executed even though the above line producing error
    goodsUom, err := service.NewGoodsService(w, r).GetGoodsUom(id)

    if err != nil {
        util.RedirectWithMessage(w, r, err.Error(), "/system/inventory/goods")
    }

}

//package utility
func RedirectWithMessage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, errMsg string, redirect string) {
    sess := session.Instance(w, r)
    sess.FlashError(errMsg)
    sess.FlashForm(r)
    sess.Save(r, w)
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirect, http.StatusFound)
    return
}
```

May i know how to stop execution rest of the code after called to function `RedirectWithMessage` ?

Putting `return` at the end of that function didn't rest of the code being executed

Im looking the equivalent of Php version of redirect in Golang:

```
fuunction foo($location){
  header(“Location : $location”);
  exit();
}

 foo("/bar"):
 echo "blah"; //this will not be executed
```

**Edited** cause of overzealous down-vote.

Yes im fully aware that i can put `return` statement after a called to `RedirectWithMessage`. I just dont want to clutter my code with `return` statement all the place.Instead i just put once inside the function.
I just wonder is there any better solution to that? Can i achieve the same behaviour like php code i show?

Comment: Do a `return` after each call of `util.RedirectWithMessage`.

Comment: Where did you put the `return`?

Comment: @Volker im fully aware of that..i just dont want to clutter my controller with `return` statement

Comment: `return` only returns from the current function, this is just how go works. Most (if not all) of your error checks should have a return statement in them or you just keep executing the handler when problems are encountered (eg: you're still proceeding on invalid ID).

Comment: If you are fully aware of the only proper solution: What is the question?

Comment: @Volker `i just dont want to clutter my controller with return statement`?

Comment: The alternative would be a giant mess of nested if/else statements. You won't find the equivalent of php's `exit`, as Go just keeps running, it's not a script that you can just exit out of. I would add that `if err != nil { handleError(); return err }` is idiomatic go.

Comment: There is no "I want" in Go.

Comment: `return` is not clutter. It's useful. It's readable. It's straight-forward. It's effectively essential. If you think writing good code is clutter, then there's not a lot we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was tempted to give you a `panic` `defer` way and warn you not to use it but then I realize it might be better to change the API.

You can focus the main logic of the function and return the error to the caller, and ask the caller to handle the error the way you want, e.g. redirect, log and so on.

```
func (self *GoodsController) GoodsEditGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err:=self.goodsEditGet(w,r)
    if err!=nil { //Note 1
        util.RedirectWithMessage(w, r, err.Error(), "/system/inventory/goods")
    }
}

func (self *GoodsController) goodsEditGet(w http.ResponsWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    tmpID, ok := vars["id"]
    sess := session.Instance(w, r)

    if !ok {
        tpl.Error("Invalid goods id")
    }

    id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(tmpID, 10, 64)

    goods, err := service.NewGoodsService(w, r).GetGoodsDetail(id)

    if err != nil {
        //This utility function will not stop the rest of the code being executed
        return err //Note 2
    }

    goodsUom, err := service.NewGoodsService(w, r).GetGoodsUom(id)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note 1: You would possibly want to handle more specified errors, not just dealing with nil and non-nil. In that case, type assertion may be a good idea.

Note 2: You would possibly want to wrap the error. You can try [`github/pkg/errors`](https://github.com/pkg/errors), a good package dealing with erros written by Dave Cheney.

Note 3: It is adviced against to use `self` as receiver name, as it is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Yes im thinking about panic and defer too..i try to ask here wether its plausible..i put the redirect inside function to make it easy for calling code..it can prevent calling code from forget to put `return` after call to redirect that lead to hard to trace bug..thx for ur input

Comment: Do you also want to redirect if `ParseInt` fails (which you're not checking) or you have an invalid id (on which you're not returning)? This solution works only if all error conditions should result in the same outcome.

Comment: @Marc This only deals with that but with a type assertion (or select of value) to determine the error that returned, it can handle multiple types of errors.

Comment: True, but then it's just as simple to return in the original error case. While your solution does work, I'm not sure I would recommend it. Overall, it seems like trying to avoid the `if err {...; return err }` pattern for no good reason.

Comment: @Marc I would say the problem of the orignal code is not avoiding `return err`, but being too verbose on error handling. While it is true `if err!=nil { ... } ` patter is common, it does diverse the code in a way. Dealing all kinds of errors in a single place would make the logic more centered, and in my opinion, more idomatic.

Comment: ... If it is simply a `panic(err)` or `log.Info` or `fmt.Println`, I would surely recommend just adding return every use. But if there is some non-trivial logic there, I would consider to have a place dedicate to the error handling.